# Swagger.io - API docs generator

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I would like to use Swagger.io for my API docs.
The problem is that their documentation, to put it mildly, sucks.

I am using their editor: http://editor.swagger.io and want to download the out-coming result exactly as it seen on this page (including the html template).

Somebody have done it before? I just can't download something that just works.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a very simple CSS in Swagger Editor to make it only show the docs. It's a hack, but if you really want to do this it's a way to do this

```
 .main-header, .editor.pane, .ui-splitbar {
     display: none;
 }

 .preview.pane {
     left: 0 !important;
     top: 0 !important;
     right: 0 !important;
     width: 100% !important;
 }
```